# MapView - how to zoom to the viewport returned by the GeoCode service

Tags: android, android-mapview

When I receive a geocode response from the GeoCode service from Google, it contains a recommended viewport describe as Lat/Lng pairs.

How can I zoom in/out to the recommended viewport ?

Comment: use mapView.animateTo(geopoint);

Comment: is it what you were lokking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to use MapController.zoomToSpan(...).
Find the difference between the North/East coordinates and the South/West coordinates and then call the zoomToSpan method.

Fuller description can be found here [Getting map zoom level for given bounds on Android like on JS Google Maps API: map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979165/getting-map-zoom-level-for-given-bounds-on-android-like-on-js-google-maps-api-m) in user640688 posting.

Answer (score 1):

In order to navigate to particular lat long you need to use the below method.

replace geopoint with your lat and long

```
mapView.animateTo(geopoint);
```

Comment: As you can see from the method name, this method moves to a lat/lng.
It does not change the visible zoomed area area.
What Google returns in its geocode answer is a Lat/Lng pair representing North East and South West coordinates.
I am needing to change the zoom level to be as close to this bounded zone as possible.